# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_ssl’ in RHEL6 but works in RHEL7

Tags: python, ssl, import, rhel6

I have installed python 3.9 in our buildfarm which has RHEL6 and RHEL7 OS. Some Unit tests are failing with below error on RHEL6. But same unit tests working fine on RHEL7. This means python installation is fine but it is something todo with RHEL6? Any pointers to debug this issue

Error:
import ssl
usr/software/pkgs/Python-3.9.0/lib/python3.9/ssl.py:98: in
import _ssl # if we can’t import it, let the error propagate
E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_ssl’

Comment: Possibly the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547335/ssl-needed-for-python-3-8-on-rhel-6

Comment: Its not same. Same installation is working fine on RHEL7. That's puzzling me